How to efficiently upload large and multiple files to the server using Express and React?
I’ve developed an API using Express that allows users to upload multiple files simultaneously. The maximum file size a user can upload is 1GB. However, I’m facing a significant issue when the file size exceeds 20MB. Files below this size upload relatively quickly, but for larger files (e.g., 50MB, 400MB, 1GB), the upload process takes an excessive amount of time—sometimes between 10 to 15 minutes or even longer.
I am using React on the frontend to interact with the API, and the backend is hosted on a Hostinger VPS. The API works fine for smaller files, but performance degrades drastically with larger files.
What could be causing this delay, and how can I optimize the file upload process for larger files? Any help or suggestions for improvements would be greatly appreciated!
I’ve attempted several configurations and optimizations, but the issue persists. Locally, everything works perfectly fine—uploads of all sizes complete quickly without delays. However, once the API is deployed on the live server, larger file uploads become extremely slow.
Here is the current Nginx configuration for my domain:
server {
  client_max_body_size 2G; 
  proxy_request_buffering off;
  proxy_connect_timeout 600;
  proxy_send_timeout 600;
  proxy_read_timeout 600;
  send_timeout 600;
  gzip on;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 1024m;

  location / {
    client_body_buffer_size 128k; 
    proxy_buffer_size 128k; 
    proxy_buffers 4 256k; 
    proxy_buffering on; 
  }
}

and api route is "domain/api/media/uploads"
